# from mysql table into mulitdimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I need to insert mysql table as multidimensional array, i am trying to do it with this code :

```
        $saranb     = array();


        $sql        = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kasar2");

        while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $saranb[]= $row_user;
            }

        ?>
```

but when i tried it, it returns error because it given boolean.
(Optional) why it returns boolean
Please help me, if you have another method to do that, please post it here.
Thank you

Comment: Surely this boolean is FALSE, maybe kasar2 table doesn't exist or you haven't any open connection

Answer (score 0):

The function [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns FALSE if there are no more rows to fetch. In your case, your query isn't getting results and you got a boolean (FALSE).

Comment: Thanks, there is a problem in my code so it returns a false